Sprite location changes based on canvas size
my game has a dynamic width and height based on the users screen size. Im setting sprites at different locations on the map. The issue is that the sprites location will be off depending on the user screen size. So on my screen its fine but if I switch to a different screen, the sprites location will be off by a few pixels. How can I make it so that no matter the screen size, the sprites location is always in the same place. The following is my config
    const parentContainer = document.getElementById("feed-container");
    const canvasWidth = parentContainer.clientWidth;
    const canvasHeight = parentContainer.clientHeight;
    const config: Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig = {
      type: Phaser.AUTO,
      width: canvasWidth,
      height: canvasHeight,
      // render: {
      //   pixelArt: true,
      //   antialias: true,
      // },
      parent: "phaser-container",
      physics: {
        default: "arcade",
        arcade: {
          gravity: { x: 0, y: 0 },
          fixedStep: false,
        },
      },
      scene: { preload: preload, create: create, update: update },
    };

example of how I'm currently positioning a sprite
      let tree = this.physics.add
          .sprite(500, 300, "tree")
          .setScale(0.5);


Small missmatches can be rounding Errors. If it is more than a rounding error can you, give a concret example with which screensizes this can be seen? Just to reproduce it.

if you mean relative to the screen, you should use the code below
this.iw = window.innerWidth;
this.ih = window.innerHeight;

then use this code
      let tree = this.physics.add
          .sprite(500*this.iw, 300*this.ih, "tree")
          .setScale(0.5*(this.iw/this.ih));

